# How to provide a link to download a csv from sas stp

Tags: sas

I need to provide a sample file for the user to understand the formant of the file which they have to upload.
I'm keeping a file /SASData/dummy/sample.csv in compute server. When the user click the download button it should download this file

Comment: Click on the link in what webpage?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored process which when executed sends a file to the user's browser to download by using a binary copy to stream the file to _webout.  This method can be used to return a CSV, PDF, or any file.  The key parts are to set content type and content disposition appropriately, and the step for the binary copy.  Here is an untested example adapted from https://support.sas.com/kb/20/784.html and https://support.sas.com/kb/32/634.html

```
data _null_ ;
  rc = stpsrv_header('Content-type','text/csv');
  rc = stpsrv_header('Content-disposition','attachment; filename=csvforuser.csv') ;
run ;

data _null_ ;
  length data $1 ;
  infile  "/somedir/mycsv.csv" recfm=n ;
  file _webout  recfm=n mod ;
  input data  $char1. @@ ;
  put data $char1. @@ ;
run ;
```

When the user clicks a link to execute that stored process, their browser should download csvforuser.csv and open it in whatever application they have configured to open CSV files.

There are other ways to do a binary copy in SAS which may be faster, you might want to google more approaches.

Comment: I would also try `FCOPY()`

Answer (score -1):

In short, as Quentin says, you need to set the headers and stream the content.

The following macro will do all this for you, and be compatible across SAS EBI, Viya, and SASjs Server:

https://core.sasjs.io/mp__streamfile_8sas.html